# Print a integer vector as decimal number

Tags: r

If you declare a numeric vector with a mix of decimal and integer values and print it, all of them are converted to a decimal number.

```
s <- c(0, 1.1, 2, 3)
print(s)
[1] 0.0 1.1 2.0 3.0
```

but if you use *cat* instead of *print*, each number is formatted according to its type.

```
cat(s, sep=" ")
0 1.1 2 3
```

How can you print a numeric vector using *cat* but converting the values to decimal numbers as *print* does?

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use format:

```
cat(format(s,digits=2))
```

Comment: This will no longer work for integer vectors, instead use `cat(format(s, nsmall = 2))`

Answer (score 9):

for example:

```
> cat(sprintf("%.01f", s))
0.0 1.1 2.0 3.0
```